# Find distribution that minimises a function of its moments

Tags: distributions, optimization, optimal

Imagine a probability density function $f(x)$, defined for positive $x$, and let's note its $n$th non-centred moment $x_{n}$. The mean $x_{1}$ is fixed (and positive).

How can I find $f(x)$ that minimises some given function of its moments? In my case $\frac{  x_{3}+x_{1}^{3}-2x_{1}x_{2}  }{  (x_{2}-x_{1}^{2})^{2}  }$.

I tried to take the gateau derivative of that expression in the direction of a test function $h(x)$, and setting the result to be zero for any $h(x)$. In the end I find a relation involving a few moments of $f(x)$ and the variable $x$, which makes no sense. Would you have any idea of the correct approach here?

Comment: Any symmetric distribution with $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 > 0$ will have that function value equal to zero.   If you want to truly minimize it, then see what the limit is as $x_3 \to -\infty$, and you'll realize that you aren't going to succeed in your goal.

Comment: $f(x)$ is defined only for positive $x$.

Comment: Please edit your post to include all such assumptions you are making about $f.$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross posted on math overflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356598/find-distribution-that-minimises-a-function-of-its-moments).